# How to make a python instance inherit all of the behavior of one of its attributes?

Tags: python, oop, metaprogramming

Let's say I have a python class:

```
class A:
    baz = 1

    def bar(self, x):
        return self.baz * x
```

Now let's say I have a second class, keeps an instance of the first class  as an attribute:

```
class B:
    def __init__(self, a, z):
        self.a = a
        self.z = z

    @property
    def baz(self):
        return z
```

Notice that `B` does not inherit from class `A`; it's not even aware of it.

How can I make an instance of `B` *act like* an instance of `A`, except for the behavior explicitly given in the definition of `B`? For example, if I want

```
a = A()
b = B(a, 2)
assert b.bar(2) == 4
```

that is, use `A.bar` but passing in `b` as `self`. To get this behavior, it's not enough to just do something like

```
class B:
    ...

    def getattr(self, attribute):
        return getattr(self.a, attribute)
```

That will allow any method not defined on `self` to be looked up on `self.a`. This works for constants and static methods, but for instance methods it's wrong, because `b.bar` would resolve to `A.bar` with `self` bound to `b.a`.

Basically what I want to do is dynamically insert `A` (or more generally, whatever the type of `a` in `B.__init__` is) into the MRO for that instance. In other words, to make `B` inherit from whatever the type of `a` is, on a per-instance basis.

Is such a thing possible?

Answer (score 0):

A hackey way: you can do the method binding yourself in `__getattr__`, note, all functions are descriptors, so they have a `__get__` method!

```
In [47]: class A:
    ...:     baz = 1
    ...:
    ...:     def bar(self, x):
    ...:         return self.baz * x
    ...:
    ...:
    ...: class B:
    ...:     def __init__(self, a, z):
    ...:         self.a = a
    ...:         self.z = z
    ...:
    ...:     @property
    ...:     def baz(self):
    ...:         return self.z
    ...:
    ...:     def __getattr__(self, attribute):
    ...:         try:
    ...:             attr =  getattr(type(self.a), attribute)
    ...:         except AttributeError:
    ...:             return getattr(self.a, attribute)
    ...:
    ...:         if callable(attr):
    ...:             return attr.__get__(self)
    ...:         return attr
    ...:
    ...:
    ...:

In [48]: a = A()
    ...: b = B(a, 2)
    ...: b.bar(2)
    ...:
Out[48]: 4
```